# Tensorflow Serving Illegal Instruction core dumped docker image

Tags: docker, tensorflow

Here is the full error message

```
/usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh: line 3:     7 Illegal instruction  
(core dumped) tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501
--model_name=${MODEL_NAME} --model_base_path=${MODEL_BASE_PATH}/${MODEL_NAME} "$@"
```

I have just upgraded my hardware and I am trying to build the docker tensorflow-serving image. I know the issue is in an image with incompatible CPU instructions.

Here is the result of lscpu command:

> Architecture: x86_64
>
> CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
>
> Byte Order:                      Little Endian
>
> Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
>
> CPU(s):                          4
>
> On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
>
> Thread(s) per core:              2
>
> Core(s) per socket:              2
>
> Socket(s):                       1
>
> NUMA node(s):                    1
>
> Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
>
> CPU family:                      6
>
> Model:                           165
>
> Model name:                      Intel(R) Pentium(R) Gold G6400 CPU @
> 4.00GHz
>
> Stepping:                        3
>
> CPU MHz:                         4000.858
>
> CPU max MHz:                     4000.0000
>
> CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
>
> BogoMIPS:                        7999.96
>
> Virtualization:                  VT-x
>
> L1d cache:                       64 KiB
>
> L1i cache:                       64 KiB
>
> L2 cache:                        512 KiB
>
> L3 cache:                        4 MiB
>
> NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
>
> Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Vulnerable
>
> Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
>
> Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
>
> Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
>
> Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass
> disabled via prctl and seccomp
>
> Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers
> and __user pointer sanitization
>
> Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB
> conditional, RSB filling
>
> Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
>
> Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
>
> Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8
> apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse
> sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_
> tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq
> dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg cx16 xtpr pdcm p
> cid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch
> cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_e
> nhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust smep erms invpcid mpx rdseed smap
> clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves
> dtherm arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities

Could you help me with correct options for my CPU to build the image?

Answer (score 0):

This CPU [does not support AVX instructions](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/pentium/g6400.html):

> Instruction Set Extensions: Intel® SSE4.1, Intel® SSE4.2

If it had, you would see the `avx` flag in the long string reported by lscpu(1).

[Tensorflow build instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#configuration_options) mention the requirement:

> **Note:** Starting with TensorFlow 1.6, binaries use AVX instructions which may not run on older CPUs.

Your best bet is to downgrade to TF 1.5, compatible with the platform, if the full TensorFlow is required. If you are after inference only, consider converting the model to [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite), which is much less demanding of the platform. The conversion is not automatic, however, and may require quite an effort, depending on the model.

The main obstacle for me was that not all ops had direct or fused equivalents in TF Lite. This may have changed since.